# Total derivative product rule

Tags: calculus, derivatives

**Definition:** Let $U\in \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open set. Let $a\in U$ and $f:U\to \mathbb{R}^m$. We say that $f$ is total differentiable at $a$ if there exists
a matrix $T\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and a continuous function $\varphi:U\to \mathbb{R}^m$ such that 
$$
f(x)=f(a)+T(x-a)+|| x-a ||\varphi(x),\quad x\in U,\quad \varphi(a)=0.
$$ 
**Product rule:** 
Let $U\in \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open set. Let $a\in U$, $f:U\to \mathbb{R}$ and $g:U\to \mathbb{R}^m$. If $f$ and $g$ are total differentiable at $a$, then $fg$ is total differentiable at $a$.

I tried to write 
$$
f(x)=f(a)+T_1(x-a)+||x-a||\varphi_1(x),
$$
and 
$$
g(x)=g(a)+T_2(x-a)+||x-a||\varphi_2(x).
$$
then one obtain 
\begin{align}
&f(x)g(x)\\
&=f(a) g(a) + (f(a) T_2 + g(a) T_1) (x - a) + ||x - a|| \left(\varphi_1(x)\varphi_2(x)+f(a)\varphi_2(x)+g(a)\varphi_1(x)\right)+ T_1(x-a)T_2(x-a)
\end{align}
I just not sure how to continue becuase of this extra term "$T_1(x-a)T_2(x-a)$"
Any answer? Thanks

Comment: you need to be more careful about the order of the products. Matrix multiplication isn't commutative. Concerning your question: $T_1(x-a)T_2(x-a)$ is a order 2 term and thus part of the "$\varphi$" for $fg$.

Comment: @user251257 thanks for your comment. What you mean exactly by " order 2 term and thus part of the "φ" "?

Comment: in the definition of differentiable there is a matrix $T$ and function $\varphi$. since $T_1(x-a)T_2(x-a) /\|x-a\|$ goes to $0$ for $x\to a$, it is a part of $\varphi$.

Answer (score 1):

The condition on $\varphi $ is that $\varphi(x-a)\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow a$.

Since $T_{1}$ and $T_{2}$ are matrices of real numbers, there are $K_{1}>0$ and $K_{2}>0$ such that

$$ \left \| T_{1}(x-a) \right \|\leq K_{1}\left \| x-a \right \| $$

and

$$ \left \| T_{2}(x-a) \right \|\leq K_{2}\left \| x-a \right \|, $$

so that

$$ T_1(x-a) T_2(x-a) $$

satisfies

$$ \left \|  T_1(x-a) T_2(x-a) \right \|\leq K_{1}K_{2}\left \| x-a \right \|^{2}, $$

i.e.

$$ \left \|  \frac{ T_1(x-a) T_2(x-a)}{x-a} \right \|\leq K_{1}K_{2}\left \| x-a \right \|. $$

This means we may take

$$ \varphi _{3}(x)=\frac{T_1(x-a) T_2(x-a)}{\left \| x-a \right \|}. $$

Then $\varphi _{3}$ satisfies  $\varphi _{3}(x-a)\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow a$, and so finally we then have

$$ T_1(x-a) T_2(x-a)=\varphi _{3}(x)\left \| x-a \right \|, $$

which is what you need.